# The Comeonin.Bcrypt checkpw method returns false after I Reset Password - Elixir

Tags: elixir, hmac, password-hash

I am using Comeonin.Bcrypt for doing the password encryption. It is working fine while registering account and I can Login successfully. But, once I reset my password, the checkpw method always returns false for new password and old password. I am using the below method to generate the password hash.

```
defp put_pass_digest(changeset) do   
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: raw_passwd}} = cs ->
        put_change(cs, :password_digest, hashpwsalt(raw_passwd))
      changeset ->
        changeset
    end
  end
```

This is the change password method:

```
def change_password(conn, %{"user" => %{"code" => code, "password" => password, "repeated_password" => repeated_password}}) do
    token = Repo.one(fetch_valid_token_q(code, "password_reset"))
    changeset = User.change_password_changeset(token.user, %{password: password, repeated_password: repeated_password})
    if changeset.valid? do
      Repo.update(changeset)
      render(conn, "password_changed.html")
    else
      changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, %{})
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Wrong, try again!")
      |> render("reset_password.html", code: code, changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

The changeset definition is:

```
def change_password_changeset(%User{} = schema, params) do
    schema
    |> changeset(params)
    |> validate_required([:password, :repeated_password])
    |> validate_password()
    |> passwords_match?()
    |> put_pass_digest
  end
```

Below are the methods called on login.

```
def login_user(args, _resolution) do
    with {:ok, user}         <- fetch_user_and_verify_password(args.session_input),
         {:ok, jwt, _claims} <- Guardian.encode_and_sign(user, :access)
    do
      {:ok, %{user: user, token: jwt}}
    else
      {:error, :incorrect_login_credentials} ->
        Errors.auth_required
    end
  end

def fetch_user_and_verify_password(params) do
    user = Repo.get_by(User, email: String.downcase(params.email))

    if check_password(params.password, user) do
      {:ok, user}
    else
      {:error, :incorrect_login_credentials}
    end
  end
defp check_password(password, user), do: checkpw(password, user.password_digest)
```

I have checked DB. The updated password_digest is properly saved in DB. Not sure what is the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling `checkpw`?

Comment: I have added the methods called on login.

Comment: Where do the `args` for `login_user/2` come from? You are comparing `args.session_input.password` with the DB `password_digest` result for the user specified by `args_session_input.email`. Is the data inside `args` correct? Also are you executing different code on password updates to password creation? It'd be simpler to debug if both used the same execution path.

Comment: The args for the login method would be as : %{email: "jeena.rose@mailinator.con", password: "0c30eda324cc9136aeb66ee8170719c3c43640be0868e72eba0bb78383c5c851"}
Also, I am using the same method for creating the password_hash at registration and reset password. @AdamMillerchip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

The first level of HMAC calculation was missing in my Reset Password feature. I used below cryptographic hash function for calculating the same.

```
def to_hash(ast) do
    :sha256
    |> :crypto.hash(ast)
    |> Base.encode16
  end
```

Now it works fine!

Thanks everyone who responded.